# Using nested SQL statement to filter without affecting count

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if there's a way to filter results without affecting a count column. I have orders, employees and services tables. I have a query that shows services completed by employees, counts the number of employees on each service and calculates price per employee per service. What I'd like to do is filter out only services completed by a specific employee, but keep the count for the number of employees the same. The following query shows what I want, but whenever I add an employee id to the WHERE clause, the employee count drops to 1, obviously.

```
SELECT R.`order_id`, R.`service_id`, S.`name` AS 'service_name', Rprice.`price` AS 'service_price', COUNT(R.`employee_id`) AS 'number_employees', ROUND(Rprice.`price` / COUNT(R.`employee_id`), 2) AS 'price_employee_service' FROM `R_services_employees_orders` R
JOIN `R_order_service_price` Rprice ON R.`order_id` = Rprice.`order_id` AND R.`service_id` = Rprice.`service_id`
JOIN `Employees` E ON R.`employee_id` = E.`id`
JOIN `Orders` O on R.`order_id` = O.`id`
JOIN `Services` S on R.`service_id` = S.`id`
WHERE NOT E.`department` = 'o' 
AND O.`completed` BETWEEN '2017-04-26' AND '2017-05-06'
GROUP BY R.`order_id`, R.`service_id`
ORDER BY R.`order_id`, R.`service_id`;
```

I've tried using subqueries, but I can't seem to get the right query. Thanks in advance.

The Table structure is below

```
CREATE TABLE `Employees` (
  `id` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Enter P R or M',
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `Orders` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `completed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `R_order_service_price` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_order_price` (`order_id`),
  KEY `FK_service_price` (`service_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_order_price` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `Orders` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_service_price` FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `Services` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `R_services_employees_orders` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_id` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_order` (`order_id`),
  KEY `FK_service` (`service_id`),
  KEY `FK_employee` (`employee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_employee` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `Employees` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_order` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `Orders` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_service` FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `Services` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[Sample result from the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LCAc.png)

Comment: can you post some sample data of your tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement in your select, something like:

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN employee_id = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS employee_order_count...
```

You can aggregate any employee specific measures this way will maintaining your overall aggregates in your normal calculations.

Comment: Thank you! that works great, is there a way to put that in the WHERE clause? something like "WHERE employee_order_count = 1"? EDIT: nevermind, I did HAVING employee_order_count=1 and it worked beautifully!